# Appropriate way to handle requests with python especially in timeouts

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm using python requests to automate various API tests. What I've noticed in several occasions is, that when I "ramp up" my script and try to perform a load of tests my app stuck and I have no idea where to check what's going on.

In below code, I have 3 methods. testSingleNewLicense() is just a way to call single license and was extracted to post a question here (since I can't share all my code and licenses with you)

testURL() is actually performing requests, and I tried to implement try / except part since I thought I'll get something here (not sure if that part actually works)

string ResponseToJson() is again, just cosmetic one to print proper results out.

When in my main part of code I put while / except, I wanted my code to run for a while (soak test), but it randomly just stops. It stops after "print (url) in "testURL()".

Sometimes after 4 runs, sometimes 21, 7, 9, 32 ... (That print(i) in main)

What am I missing? How can I see what python script is doing when it's "doing nothing"?

I'm using PyCharm  / Python 3

```
try:
    i=0
    while True:
        testSingleNewLicense()
        print (i)
        i+=1
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    exit

def testSingleNewLicense():     
    sortedJsonTest = stringResponseToJson(urlLive3)
    print ("FutureLive: " + sortedJsonTest)

def testUrl(url, headers="", username="", password=""):
    print ("Tested Url:")
    print (url)
    try:
        print("pre")
        #response = requests.get("http://www.stojakovic.net", timeout=0.004)
        response = requests.get(url,headers=headers, timeout=0.85)
        print("post")
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print ("Me :" + str(e))
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout as e:
        print ("Too slow!")

print(response.request.headers)
print ("resp:" + str(response.status_code))
print (response.headers)
if (response.status_code != 200):
    print ("Not authorized", + response.status_code)
    return response.status_code, response.text
else:
    return response.status_code, response.text
pass

def stringResponseToJson(url, headers=""):
    code,content = testUrl(url, headers)
    if (code!=200):return content
    jsonT = json.loads(content)
    return json.dumps(jsonT,sort_keys=True)
```

Comment: Add a print right before and right after requests.get() to make sure that is the call that gets blocked. If it is, try to add timeout setting (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#timeouts)

Comment: I've edit my post and tried timeouts, but ... In case that I use commented dummy response (going to website and trying to get it lightening fast) i'll get "Me: error" printed. 

However, If I use uncommented response, it fails with "socket.timeout: timed out" ...

That's kinda OK, but I want to ignore those timed out and continue my script, but it fails and stops.

Comment: Sounds like maybe you are not catching the right exception. Try to add except Exception as e: and print type(e) to see what you should be catching.

Comment: Well... printing exception type gave me: <class 'socket.timeout'>

Comment: Well, maybe you should be catching that :)

Comment: Hm.. :) I thought my first line - except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e: is there to read all the exceptions? (as per documentation) ...

Comment: The docs say "All exceptions that Requests explicitly raises". RequestException inherits from IOError. It seems that requests catches and handles socket.error, but not socket.timeout for some reason. It looks like an actual bug that has been reported https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/1236

Comment: Anyway, the solution is to catch socket.timeout